# MySQL Query Grouped Conditional Count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Here is the mySQL table data:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║ USER ║   DATE   ║ NUMDOWNLOADS ║
╠════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ John ║ xx-xx-xx ║      1       ║
║  2 ║ Mary ║ xx-xx-xx ║      3       ║
║  3 ║ John ║ xx-xx-xx ║      5       ║
║  4 ║ Mary ║ xx-xx-xx ║      2       ║
║  5 ║ Mary ║ xx-xx-xx ║      6       ║
║  6 ║ John ║ xx-xx-xx ║      7       ║
║  7 ║ John ║ xx-xx-xx ║      1       ║
║  8 ║ Mary ║ xx-xx-xx ║      8       ║
║  9 ║ Mary ║ xx-xx-xx ║      9       ║
╚════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I want to accomplish is to group the data by USER, and display the total NUMDOWNLOADS per USER where NUMDOWNLOADS is > X. For example, if X=5:

John: 1 (since 1 NUMDOWNLOADS > 5, and others count collectively as 1)
Mary: 3 (since 3 NUMDOWNLOADS > 5, and others count collectively as 1)

So, (1) output per user, and (2) output total, which in this case would be 4. Clear as mud :) Ideas on statement to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is here. Try it

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(NUMDOWNLOADS)
FROM table_name
WHERE NUMDOWNLOADS > 5
GROUP BY USER
```

Comment: Perfect, works - others too, but you were first so I accepted yours. Thanks everyone. And to grand total I figured out this: SELECT SUM(count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(NUMDOWNLOADS) AS count FROM table_name WHERE NUMDOWNLOADS > 5 GROUP BY USER) AS A

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USER, COUNT(NUMDOWNLOADS)
FROM downloads
WHERE NUMDOWNLOADS > 5
GROUP BY USER
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45ed0/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to count records where `NUMDOWNLOADS > 5`:

```
select USER, count(*)
from myTable
where NUMDOWNLOADS > 5
group by USER
```

The `WHERE` filter is performed *before* any grouping is done, so first this query filters out any rows that do not match `NUMDOWNLOADS > 5`, *then* it groups by USER and counts.

---

Alternatively if there is something about your actual query that requires you to use a conditional sum, you can do so as well:

```
select USER, sum(case when NUMDOWNLOADS > 5 then 1 else 0 end)
from myTable
group by USER
```